# Component is 'undefined' when using dynamic import

Tags: node.js, webpack, dynamic-import

I'm having an issue using dynamic imports in a webpack / react application. Here is my code:

```
loader: (router) => import('../components/pages/home').then(component => {

  console.log(component)
  debugger;
  return router(component.default)
}
```

For some reason the module seems to be imported correctly in that it satisfies the import function conditions - i.e.

```
typeof module === "object" && module && module.__esModule
```

However the component remains undefined. The return value is:

```
{HomePage: undefined, __esModule: true}
```

Weirdly, if I add a static import of the same component at the top of the file then the import works as expected - obviously this is not what I want :D

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've also been having the same issue, did you find a resolution?

Comment: Actually I did find a resolution for my case. I'll post the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

So to fix my issue I had to replace ALL "require.ensure" functions with dynamic import.

I also had to explicitly add some css files to my webpack vendor bundle as they were being removed by the bundler when required by lazy-loaded modules.

```
'vendor': [
   './src/less/vendor.less',

   // HACK - Explicitly adding these files to the vendor.
   // They are incorrectly removed from the bundle when required by 
   // style imports in async modules
   // https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack- 
   // plugin/issues/456#issuecomment-340287722

   "style-loader/addStyles",
   "css-loader/lib/css-base",
  ],
```

I'm not sure if this will work for you TBH but best of luck